# Set Camera for Procedurally generated map by script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game where each time a new level is loaded, it will pick the level's width and height config and spawn as is.

It's a top down level which look like this
[image]

The only problem is the camera won't fit the the level as it grows or shrinks and I have no idea so far to make this works.

The only idea I can think of that I could get the 4 corner tiles when I spawn the level. Then lerp camera FOV until all 4 are visible, but that only solve the expanding. The shrinking however still not.

Any hint or suggestions is really appreciated!

Comment: is your camera perspective or orthographic?

Comment: my camera is perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your, lucky! I just happen to have worked on something like this recently.

Assuming you will not want to change the rotation of the camera you can do the following

1. Get `Bounds` you want to focus on - either you provide them somewhere in your scene (could e.g. be a `BoxCollider`) or you just grap them all from all the objects you want to see like e.g.

   ```
   private static bool TryGetCombinedRendererBoundsInChildren(this GameObject gameObject, out Bounds bounds)
   {
       var renderers = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
       if (renderers.TryGetCombinedBounds(out bounds))
       {
           return true;
       }

       bounds = new Bounds(gameObject.transform.position, Vector3.zero);

       return false;
    }

    private static bool TryGetCombinedBounds(this IList<Renderer> renderers, out Bounds bounds)
    {
        if (renderers.Count == 0)
        {
            bounds = default;
            return false;
        }

        bounds = renderers[0].bounds;

        for (var i = 1; i < renderers.Count; i++)
        {
            var renderer = renderers[i];

            if (!renderer)
            {
                continue;
            }

            bounds.Encapsulate(renderer.bounds);
        }

        return true;
    }
   ```
2. Then calculate the required distance to fit those bounds into the camera viewport. For simplification you could just calculate two distances, one for fitting horizontal, one for fitting vertical and then just pick the higher distance. Something like e.g.

   ```
    private static float CalculatePerspectiveFocusDistance(Camera camera, Bounds boundsToFocus)
    {
        var objectSize = boundsToFocus.extents.magnitude;

        var verticalFov = camera.fieldOfView;
        var horizontalFov = 2 * Mathf.Atan(Mathf.Tan(verticalFov * Mathf.Deg2Rad * 0.5f) * camera.aspect) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        var verticalDistance = objectSize / Mathf.Tan(0.5f * verticalFov * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        var horizontalDistance = objectSize / Mathf.Tan(0.5f * horizontalFov * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

        var cameraDistance = Mathf.Max(verticalDistance, horizontalDistance);

        return cameraDistance;
    }
   ```
3. Then finally you use this calculated distance and apply it to the camera position like e.g.

   ```
    public static void Focus(this Camera camera, GameObject target)
    {
        if(target.TryGetCombinedRendererBoundsInChildren(out var bounds))
        {
            var cameraDistance = CalculatePerspectiveFocusDistance(camera, bounds);
            var objectCenter = boundsToFocus.center;

            camera.transform.position = objectCenter - camera.transform.forward * cameraDistance;
        }
    }
   ```

---

Note that due to the simplification of just going once in X and ones in Y direction and the fact that `Bounds` in Unity are always world aligned this is only an approximation and not always a perfect fit.

To be sure there is no overlapping I for myself simply added a certain buffer to the `objectSize` for leaving some whitespace around the focus like e.g.

```
 var objectSize = boundsToFocus.extents.magnitude * (1 + someFactor);
```

e.g. `0.5` will not try and fit the object perfectly into the camera but will leave `0.5` times the objects size around the object on all sizes.

---

(in my case I also did adjust rotation first - basically just an extension of the above though. In that case you would just first make the camera look at the center instead of sticking to `camera.transform.forward`)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to implement something like this while working on a game.

If you want to maintain a perspective camera projection, I suggest instead of changing the FOV; changing the distance from camera to the level.

With some basic trigonometry you will be able to calculate how far away your camera needs to move. Using your camera FOV, previous level width, camera distance from the level, and the current level width.

**Here is some guidance**

We basically need to know how much something in worldspace has horizontally grown, compared to it's previous size. Like your level.
**(growth ratio)**

And the ratio between horizontal space and **depth** of your **camera**. Using your **FOV** (which is a viewport angle) and trigonometry.

```
  A
----- <- Vertical space size (half)
\   |
 \  | B <- Camera Depth (distance to your level)
  \ |
   \| 
    * <- FOV angle (half)
```

With trigonometry your FOV (divided by 2) and Camera Depth form a right sided triangle. And you can calculate the relation between side A and B using your FOV and trigonometry. (in this case the relation between A and B is `tan(FOV/2)`)

If Side A grows by this much and we know the relation between A and B. We can calculate what the new size of B is.

Okay so now we know the ratio between A and B. How would you apply this to your level. This is something you will have to find out on your own :)

Hope this is enough guidance.

*(note: If your level grows vertically; replace horizontally with vertically. And beaware that the set FOV is only for horizontal viewports.)*